# Determine the general solution for $2\cos 2x−5\cos x+2=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the general solution for $2\cos 2x−5\cos x +2=0$

my answer I got was : $1.05+n\pi, 4.19+n\pi$

Answer (score 1):

$$\implies 2(2\cos^2x-1)-5\cos x+2=0\iff \cos x(4\cos x-5) =0$$

If $\cos x=0,x =\frac{(2m+1)\pi}2$ where $m$ is any integer

If $4\cos x-5=0, \cos x=\frac54>1$ but  for real $x, -1\le \cos x\le 1$

Comment: so am I correct?

Comment: I would like it in my form

Comment: So, $x=m\pi+\frac\pi2=m\pi+1.57079632679$ If $m$ is even, $=2n$(say), $x=2n\pi+1.57079632679$ and if $m$ is odd $=(2n+1)$(say), $x=(2n+1)\pi+1.57079632679=2n\pi+4.71238898038$

Comment: @user73122 - you have given a number plus a multiple of $\pi$ - this is much the same - the worst you have to do is to compute $\frac {\pi}2$. The answer given here is exact, not approximate, though. Is your $1.05$ an approximation of $\frac {\pi}3$?

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that $\cos(2x) \equiv \cos^2x-\sin^2x$ and so

$$2\cos(2x)-5\cos x + 2 \equiv 2\cos^2x - 2\sin^2x - 5\cos x + 2$$

Then we know that $\sin^2x = 1-\cos^2x$, meaning that

$$2\cos(2x)-5\cos x + 2 \equiv 4\cos^2x - 5\cos x$$

We can factorise to give $(4\cos x - 5)\cos x$. The solutions are then just $\cos x = 0$ since $\cos x = \tfrac{5}{4}$ has no real solutions. Hence $x \in \{\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$

Comment: The answers it gives.. for multipe choice are